# Hugo: adding http-equiv="refresh" content="0 on build. Make it stop?

Tags: javascript, html, go, hugo

I have a very small Hugo site built, which I'm trying to deploy to Netlify. I'm getting an unexpected infinite loop when I build the site, though it appears to work in dev using `hugo serve --ignoreCache --disableFastRender --noHTTPCache -D`.

The site is comprised of two pages:

- `/`
- `/contact/`

In terms of the contact page, it's directly in the `content` folder, and is as follows:

```
---
title: "Contact"
draft: false
date: "2020-02-25"
type: "page"
layout: "page"
aliases:
- /contact.html
- /blog/contact/
- /blog/contact.html
---

{{< contactformwide >}}
```

I then have the contact form in `themes/MYTHEME/layouts/shortcodes/contactformwide.html`.

I have a very weird bug, where when I build the site using `hugo serve --ignoreCache --disableFastRender --noHTTPCache -D` it works fine. When I try to deploy it to netlify or build it locally using `hugo`, the `/contact/` page gets stuck in an infinite loop. No errors are thrown when building, it just seems to try and try again to load the page, to no avail.

I have tried to adjust `baseURL` in my `config.yaml` to the appropriate domain for production, but that didn't help.

The HTML of the page this is rendering (and re-rendering, and re-rendering) at `/contact/` is as follows (this is the version that's from Netlify, hence `mellifluous-marzipan`):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>https://mellifluous-marzipan-3893e2.netlify.app/contact/</title>
            <link rel="canonical" href="https://mellifluous-marzipan-3893e2.netlify.app/contact/"/>
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://mellifluous-marzipan-3893e2.netlify.app/contact/" />
        </head>
    </html>
```

This HTML bears essentially no relationship, except beyond the first four lines, to what I'm expecting to render.

I assume the issue is that `<meta http-equiv="refresh" ...`, but where is that coming from? Why doesn't it appear in dev? I have only the following two `http-equiv` in my usual `head`, and the main site (uses the same `head`) is <s>up right now</s> (**EDIT:** bug fixed), so you can see what the `head` looks like:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**EDIT:** I have just noticed that the page I want (what I get as `webaddress/contact` in my development environment, is stored at `public/contact/contact.html` in the build.

The same result occurs whether I click a link from `/` (which works fine), or manually go to `/contact/`.

Anyone can help me crack this? I can provide access to repo, etc., but maybe the answers obvious and I'm just too noob to see it? Maybe it has to do with the aliases for the `/contact/` page?

If it helps, when I had baseURL set to another URL, I was just getting the 404 from the `baseURL/contact/` I was being redirected to, not this infinite loop.

**EDIT:** I found that the correct page is on the netlify site, <s>here</s> (**EDIT:** bug fixed). It's being placed in `/public/contact/index.html`.

**EDIT:** It also turns out that when I place `url: contact` in the frontmatter of `layouts/contact.md`, `public/contact.html` ceases to exist when the site is built, and just `public/contact/index.html` remains.

**EDIT:** When I place the following in the frontmatter, I get `public/contact.html` (with the correct content / page), and THE SAME PAGE **ALSO** in `public/contact/index.html`.

**EDIT:** Turns out there was some confusion between `/contact`, `/contact/`, and `contact/`. I was originally linking to `/contact/` and the fix appears to have been simply changing my links to `/contact`. Not sure why that resulted in an infinite redirect, but it's working now.

Comment: Can you either add what your code for a working page is and/or try getting rid of the aliases and see if that works?

Comment: @Gage: edited the question. The correct page is actually up on the site, the routing just doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect loop contains two different redirects:

- `/contact/` ==> `/contact`. (response status code **301**)

  ```
  $ curl -i 'https://mellifluous-marzipan-3893e2.netlify.app/contact/'
  HTTP/2 301 
  // other headers and response body truncated
  ```
- `/contact` ==> `/contact/`. (client redirect with `http-equiv="refresh"`, alias are implemented with a similar mechanism. see [How Aliases Work](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#how-aliases-work)).

  ```
  $ curl -i 'https://mellifluous-marzipan-3893e2.netlify.app/contact'
  HTTP/2 200
  // other headers truncated and response body formatted

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>https://mellifluous-marzipan-3893e2.netlify.app/contact/</title>
      <link
        rel="canonical"
        href="https://mellifluous-marzipan-3893e2.netlify.app/contact/"
      />
      <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta
        http-equiv="refresh"
        content="0; url=https://mellifluous-marzipan-3893e2.netlify.app/contact/"
      />
    </head>
  </html>
  ```

It seems that it's the first one to blame. It's most likely that the netlify redirect rules are configured incorrectly. Please check the rules in the following files to see if there is anything wrong:

- `_redirects`
- `netlify.toml`

(see [Redirects and rewrites](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/)).

Comment: Thanks @Zeke! Only thing is, I get this behaviour on my local builds as well (i.e. when I open the `filesystem://contact.html`), so I don't /think/ netlify could be to blame? Also, I have no redirects in netlify.toml, and no _redirects file.

I think your curl sleuthing will be helpful though, thanks!

Comment: But you said that "when I build the site using `hugo serve --ignoreCache --disableFastRender --noHTTPCache -D` it works fine". I'm confused. Can you provide a minimal reproducer?

Comment: turns out the answer was to change my links to `/contact` instead of `/contact/`. Still not sure why the latter resulted in an infinite redirect on running `hugo` (i.e. running from the `pulbic` folder), but not on `hugo serve --ignoreCache --disableFastRender --noHTTPCache -D`... but it's fixed. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: hmm, that's weird because `/contact` should result in the second redirect listed above according to the test before. Can you provide a reproducer?

Comment: I can't really at this point - I've lost the bug (thankfully). It was weird though. I was quite surprised the bug happened in the public build, but not in the development environment -- that was perhaps the oddest part.